# Como chamar uma função dentro de outra no Java para Android?

Tags: java, android, funções, teclado, key-value

Toda letra que o usuário digitar no `EditText`, invoca a função
`TextWatcher` que leva a um `Text-to-speech`.
Então se ele escreve 'c', o app retorna uma fala dizendo 'c'. se ele entra em seguida com 'a', retorna 'a'.
O problema é que, quando o usuário deleta o último caractere entrado, o app também retorna a letra que estiver antes da deletada.
Com o mesmo exemplo, a palavra formada seria 'ca'. Se o usuário deletar o 'a', o app retorna 'c'.

**Eu preciso fazer uma verificação da key pressionada para deletar, pois, se ela for apertada, não poderá acionar o `text-to-speech`.**

```
   editTextPrincipal.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    editTextPrincipal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (onKey == false){
                editTextPrincipal.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            }

        }
    });
```

tentei fazer essa mudança sugerida, mas não resolveu:

```
    editTextPrincipal.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
                editTextPrincipal.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Sei que esse código está errado, mas, a lógica que queria era de chamar a função `onKey` dentro do `setOnClickListener`, naquela condição de `if`.

Meu TextWatcher:

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        oqSeraFalado = editTextPrincipal.getText().toString();
        if (oqSeraFalado.length() > 1){
            oqSeraFalado = oqSeraFalado.substring(oqSeraFalado.length()-1);
            vamosFalar();
        }else{
            vamosFalar();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};

public void vamosFalar(){
    String ToSpeak = oqSeraFalado;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ToSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    tts.setPitch(1);
    tts.setSpeechRate(1);
    tts.speak(ToSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

Descobri uma coisa engraçada... eu fiz essa mudança no código:

```
    editTextPrincipal.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
            Log.e("key",keyCode+"");
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                usuarioDeletouCaracter = true;
                return usuarioDeletouCaracter;
            }
            return usuarioDeletouCaracter;

        }
    });
```

e no log, ele só pega o valor do delete do teclado apenas se não tiver nada escrito no EditText em questão. caso contrário, ele n pega o codigo de nenhuma outra tecla para a var keycode.

Comment: um pouco confuso xD

Answer (score 0):

Mikhael, pq você precisa do onClick no editText?

Se toda vez que o usuário digita algo o seu TTS deve lê-lo, acredito eu que você nem precisa controlar o listener de textChanged, você poderia chamar a função do text-to-speech direto do seu keyListener, não?

Edita essa função abaixo /

```
public void vamosFalar(String toSpeak){

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    tts.setPitch(1);
    tts.setSpeechRate(1);
    tts.speak(toSpeak, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

e chama essa função no seu onKey()

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    if ( keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL){
        vamosFalar( editTextPrincipal.getText().toString() ); //Se quiser pode validar se existe o texto no edit
    }
}
```

Comment: um amigo de sala sugeriu algo parecido mas não surtiu efeito =\

Comment: Mikhael, a idéia é não adicionar mais o watcher de textChangedListener como tu fez:
`editTextPrincipal.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);`

Acredito que dentro deste watcher "textWatcher" tu tá chamando ou executando uma função que faça o text-to-speech certo?

O mais correto ao meu ver, é você chamar essa função ou fazer essa tratativa do TTS direto no onKey()

Comment: Se possível, mostra p/ gente o código do seu textWatcher

Comment: Gabriel, acabei de editar o post incluindo o codigo do textwatcher !

Comment: Faz o teste com o edit da questão, assim você nem precisará da sua classe textWatcher, pois o onKey já é um watcher de quando foi digitado algo.